# Play a stream of G711 encoded audio using Java?

Tags: java, audio, streaming

Is it possible to use `javax.sound.sampled` or some other built-in Java library to play audio in a Java Applet? The audio is the content type `audio/basic` and is G711 encoded.

The audio stream originates from the on-board HTTP server of the Axis network camera I am using. I can also get the audio in AAC or G726 encodings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about `javax.sound`. But I remember Sun Java libraries from a long time ago which handled audio, including G.711 data. A little searching reveals [com.sun.media.sound](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/sun/media/sound/package-index.html). For decoding the G.711 data to normal PCM audio, look at either the [AlawCodec](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/sun/media/sound/AlawCodec.html) or [UlawCodec](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/sun/media/sound/UlawCodec.html) classes. Is there any other encapsulation to the audio, or is it just raw logarithmic PCM bytes with no header? If there's encapsulation, there might be other classes to process that first (something like [AuFileReader](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/sun/media/sound/AuFileReader.html)).